# RxJS cacheError((error:any) cannot accept any object type as parameter

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I used RxJS like below:

```
  catchError((error: any) => {
    if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
      .......
      if (error.status === 401) {
          .....
          return;
        }}
```

But cacheError((error:any) usage gives below error:

Argument of type `(error: any) => Observable<never> | undefined` is not assignable to parameter of type `(err: any, caught: Observable<HttpEvent<any>>) => ObservableInput<never>`.
Type `Observable<never> | undefined` is not assignable to type `ObservableInput<never>`.
Type `undefined` is not assignable to type `ObservableInput<never>`

How can I solve it? I am using rxjs 6.6.3 version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [RxJS docs / learn](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/error_handling/catch)

> Remember to return an observable from the catchError function!

So to get rid of the error, you could return empty observable `of()`:

```js
catchError((error: any) => {
    if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
      .......
      if (error.status === 401) {
          .....
          return of();
        }}
```